# How to make the parameter list of a function cleaner?

Tags: c++, optimization, struct, parameter-passing, long-parameter-list

In a video that I recently watched, [*Kate Gregory*](http://www.gregcons.com/kateblog/) suggests that if a function has a huge parameter list (e.g. 4+ parameters) one should put all those parameters in a `struct` (i.e. make them members of the struct) and after initializing an instance of the `struct`, pass it to the said function (obviously this requires refactoring the function itself too).

I have a utility function with 5 parameters which you can see below:

```
bool convert_str_to_valid_ints( const std::string_view inputStr, const std::span<int> result_ints,
                                const std::size_t expectedTokenCount, const std::vector<int>& specificTokensIndices,
                                const std::pair<int, int> acceptableRange =
                                std::pair<int, int>( std::numeric_limits<int>::min( ), std::numeric_limits<int>::max( ) ) );
```

As can be expected, calling this function in any call site introduces a massive and scary piece of code!

The above can become this:

```
// In a header file
struct ParameterList
{
    std::string_view inputStr;
    std::span<int> result_ints;
    std::size_t expectedTokenCount;
    std::vector<int> specificTokensIndices;
    std::pair<int, int> acceptableRange = std::pair<int, int>( std::numeric_limits<int>::min( ),
                                                               std::numeric_limits<int>::max( ) );
};

bool convert_str_to_valid_ints( const ParameterList& pl );
.
.
.
// in any source file that includes the said header file
const ParameterList pl { /* arguments go here */ };

bool isValid { convert_str_to_valid_ints( pl ) }; // much more readable, and possibly more performant?
```

I have tried to break it into smaller pieces (e.g. two smaller functions each with fewer parameters) but I have failed to do so since what this fucntion does can not logically be broken into two pieces and it doesn't make much sense. So I want to ask for help to see whether *Gregory*'s method will be a valid choice in this particular case or not.

Now if one says it's a valid choice, then where should I put the definition of this special purpose `struct` (my guess is inside the header in which the big function is declared so that other source files can access the struct by including the big function's header and then call the funtion)?

Comment: *"inside the header in which the big function is declared"* Yes, that's the only solution.

Comment: *"calling this function in any call site introduces a massive and scary piece of code!"* - Um, I disagree. The only "scary" parts are the decl and impl of the function itself. The actual call sites are just function calls passing five arguments, one of them optional. Regardless, the location of your struct should be commensurate to the visibility of the function. If the function is publicized in a header, then the struct should ideally come above/before that. This is no different than any parameters, of any types, for any publicized function, ever.

Comment: The number of parameters at which you should do this is not a given, it is more a mindset to keep thinking about writing readable and maintainable code. Kate often professes empathy in your naming, think about whether it will help someone else (or you future you) to understand the code better. In a way this question is opinion based :)

Comment: @WhozCraig So do you mean that passing the local `struct` of the caller to the said function by reference won't have any performance uplifts?

Comment: It will not enhance performance it is a readability/maintainability kind of things. If this function really requires 5 parameters so be it. It is more that sometimes during maintenance people tend to keep adding parameters... usually extra options, and then things get messy after a while. So with a lot of options it starts making sense to move things (options) to classes, provide various overloads with less parameters etc.

Comment: From the looks of it, this function does at least two jobs – parsing a string into integers, and validating that those integers are within a specific range – and has a misleading name. (It also seems odd to pass the expected number of integers and their positions to the function.)

Comment: @molbdnilo True, it first calls another function named `tokenize` to get the tokens (of type `std::string`). Then using a for-loop it tests each of the strings by giving them one by one to another function called `isInt`. And BTW, what is the reason you say it has a misleading name?

Comment: It has a misleading name since it apparently doesn't convert anything but only validates the input string. (And you have just described how you could break the function into several parts...)

Comment: @molbdnilo I was able to divide the function into two parts and a side of effect of doing this was more optimized code. Not only that but now there's no need for an extra struct to hold the arguments of this function since parameter count dropped to 4. Also I used std::span to make the interface even more cleaner and intuitive plus more flexible. It's interesting how some C++ 20 features make our lives easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The struct should be in a header file, probably on its own in its own header file.
Have you considered this?
Adding the convert function to the struct, so it can use the parameters directly, it also allows you to reuse them later.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <span>
#include <vector>

struct ParameterListConverter
{
    std::span<int> result_ints; // you can even set some reasonable defaults here
    std::size_t expectedTokenCount;
    std::vector<int> specificTokensIndices;
    std::pair<int, int> acceptableRange = std::pair<int, int>(std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
    std::numeric_limits<int>::max());

    bool convert(const std::string input) const
    {
        // ... your convert function using the parameters set
    };
};


int main()
{
    ParameterListConverter converter
    {
        .expectedTokenCount = 42ul
    };

    bool success = converter.convert("123,234");

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I might consider this approach.